# custom kendo listview footer : get render control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, footer

How to define custom footer in kendo listview control? For example I dont want to see bottom line with number of displayed items in simple case.In complex case I'd like to get full control using something like

```
   .FooterTemplate('...template..')
```

Comment: can you be more specific with your question? what do you mean by "simple case" and "complex case"? Are you expecting both of these cases to be handled in the same listview?

Comment: in simple case I mean just removing unneccessary elements like string 'number of displayed items...'.By the word complex case I mean total control of the footer rendered html.For example something like this: <div id=footer>  <div id=navigatebuttons></div> <div id=owncontent><div/>  </div>